# How can I track if a trace is executing?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, trace

I'm sure there's a trace here running and creating logs.

I have no idea who did this in the past ( Its here since my first day in this company ).

There's no trace of it on sp_whoisactive.

Activity monitor shows nothing.

Theres no job running.

There's no job about something like this ( I deleted all old jobs and created my own ones ).

But it's still creating this files. I can't delete if because SQL Server is using it. I can't stop this server because it's the production one. Maybe if I stop the server I can delete the files but they will be created again.

I'm sure there's no sign of a trace running.

[image]

This error log file is the same error log we can see on `error logs > current`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the log file you are referencing in your question is created by the SQL Server default trace.  You should be able to verify that by running:

```
SELECT path AS [Default Trace File]
    ,max_size AS [Max File Size of Trace File]
    ,max_files AS [Max No of Trace Files]
    ,start_time AS [Start Time]
    ,last_event_time AS [Last Event Time]
FROM sys.traces
WHERE is_default = 1
GO
```

There is additional useful information about [Different Ways to Find Default Trace Location in SQL Server](https://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Different-Ways-to-Find-Default-Trace-Location-in-SQL-Server/).

Comment: Oh Thanks. Dumb me, I completely forgot about `sys.traces`. Yes I have a result on it point to that exactly .TRC file. AS this is the oldest question I will mark it as the correct answer. I could already disable the trace. But that ERRORLOG file is still there, and I can't delete it because I'ts still in use with SQL Server. I'm gonna snoop around a little. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from sys.traces where id = 1.
```

This is the default trace.

[SQL Server Built-In Traces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293615.aspx)